# Wait for multiple scripts to load in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onload, onload-event, nested-function

I am using the onload function to wait until a script is loaded before I run my code. It works well for one script, but if I want to wait for multiple scripts I have to do something super inelegant like:

```
    aScript.onload = function() {
        bScript.onload = function() {
            runMyFunction();
        }
    }
```

Is there an easier way to wait for multiple scripts to load instead of nesting them?

Thanks!

Comment: [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the loading of your module dependencies I'd suggest you to use 
[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) library.

You can find some simple examples of usage [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#exports).